# Adding new profiles to Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have multiple gmail addresses; one for personal, one for work, one for a professional community I belong to. I'd love to be able to have them all logged in at the same time, but apparently all incognito windows share the same cookie jar, so you can only log into one in your main window and one additional in incognito.

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEMhTumFtPo) (and other sources), using separate Chrome profiles is a good way to handle this, but I don't have the Add option in my profile.

When I click my profile icon, I see this:

[image]

There's no Add link, only a default Guest user. When I click on the cog icon, it opens this:
[image]

But again, no Add.

(I'm apparently not the only one having this problem; there's a [thread on Google's help community](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/114731113/chrome-sync-personalities-can-t-add-new-profile?hl=en). I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and I'm not willing to try the one answer that suggests adding a registry key from the command line without an explanation of what it really does or where the guy found that "answer".)

I'm on Windows 10 Pro; it's not a company-managed system. *(ETA that interestingly, when I tried on my company-managed work laptop, I do see the Add option; it's only on my personal laptop that I can't do it.)* I don't think any of my plugins would cause this. Is there some setting I'm missing somewhere to allow me to enable multiple profiles?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this support thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/114731113/chrome-sync-personalities-can-t-add-new-profile?hl=en&msgid=127116940), a user got it working on a Mac by **reinstalling chrome**. Guess the same applies for windows.

(A complete and fresh installation of Chrome (and/or Chrome canary) would suffice.).

Also, make sure you have backups turned on and that you are signed in to a Google account from your default profile (as seen in the images). This would ensure that the extensions, bookmarks, etc. would get restored on the reinstallation.

Comment: Thank you, but that's the same thread I linked in my question, and as I said, I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it doesn't work (didn't work for most of the users on that thread, either.)